# Query to identify non-breaking linestrings (PGSQL with POSTGIS)

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I need a query that identifies linestrings that do not break when found at the point of another line, examples below:

Here in this case, the lines meet and break at the points:
[image: Here in this case, the lines meet and break at the points]

I need a select that finds cases when the line continues and does not break:
[image: I need a select that finds cases when the line continues and does not break]

Or like this:
[image]

It would be possible?

I tried something like this but it didn't work out very well

```
SELECT a.id, a.geom
FROM mapeamento_urbano.hid_trecho_drenagem_l AS a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM mapeamento_urbano.hid_trecho_drenagem_l AS b
    WHERE a.id != b.id
    AND ST_Touches(a.geom, b.geom)
    AND ST_Equals(ST_EndPoint(b.geom), ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom))
);
```

which returned cases like this:
[image: Image:]

Comment: I tried but it only returned lines separate from the others [Example:](https://prnt.sc/3MfJYQjkDOpZ)

Comment: What about the rest of DE-9IM and cases with more than 2 geometries? What do you do if: **1)** the other line neither starts nor ends on yours but rather runs straight through **2)** they have one or more segments in common, or are completely one "on top" of the other? Also, by *do not break* do you mean they don't start/end there, or that they don't have an internal point (turn, node, vertex) in that location?

Comment: How would you classify [these](https://dbfiddle.uk/-I7dgSmM)?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the subtle property that a line doesn't [`contain`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Contains.html) points located at its extremity ([related post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/295064/can-linestring-contain-point)).

```sql
WITH src(id,geom) as (values 
    (1, 'linestring(0 0, 0 10)'::geometry),
    (2, 'linestring(0 10, 0 11)'::geometry),
    (3, 'linestring(1 1, 0 5)'::geometry),
    (4, 'linestring(1 1, 2 2)'::geometry))
SELECT a.id, b.id, st_asText(st_intersection(a.geom,b.geom))
FROM src AS a
JOIN src AS B on st_intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
WHERE a.id != b.id 
 AND st_contains(a.geom, st_intersection(a.geom,b.geom));

 id | id | st_astext
----+----+------------
  1 |  3 | POINT(0 5)
(1 row)
```

Alternatively, you can adapt your query to look for lines where an intersection do exists at a location different than the line start or end point

```sql
 WITH src(id,geom) as (values 
    (1, 'linestring(0 0, 0 10)'::geometry),
    (2, 'linestring(0 10, 0 11)'::geometry),
    (3, 'linestring(1 1, 0 5)'::geometry),
    (4, 'linestring(1 1, 2 2)'::geometry))
SELECT a.id
FROM src AS a
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM src AS b
    WHERE a.id != b.id
    AND ST_Touches(a.geom, b.geom)
    AND NOT (
        ST_Equals(ST_EndPoint(a.geom), ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom))
        or ST_Equals(ST_startPoint(a.geom), ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom))
    )
);

 id
----
  1
(1 row)
```

Comment: I tested your query (the first one) and apparently it worked man, in relation to lines that are not drawn perfectly, would it be able to get it too?
[Image] (https://prnt.sc/ErZxZzmwzi_9)

Comment: @lucasmsqt maybe the 2nd query can be adapted to use `st_dwithin` instead of `st_equals`, but it would open other cans of worms...